# Support for WireGuard in NetworkManager

Tags: networking

As WireGuard is now becoming more used, and implemented, and available trough the main kernel, it would be nice to provide support for WireGuard in the network-settings (VPN), by upgrading the NetworkManager to one of the latest versions that do support WireGuard. Is this possible on short-term?